# Nginx server name difference

Tags: nginx

If the server ip is 10.0.0.0, but I'm mapping it to make it to have www.example.com, is the below config the correct way to do it?

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name 10.0.0.0 example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.log;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want to restrict a server to a single interface address, it needs to go with the `listen` directive:

```
server {

    listen 10.0.0.0:80;

    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.log;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

above answer, or you can just setup a basic server block

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/folderName/htdocs; // where you have your project folder and public directory
index index.html index.htm;  // add index.php here if using php files

server_name test.com www.test.com;   // desired url goes here

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

}

the tutorials from digital ocean are pretty nice - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts